# Combo box items removal upon selection of a particular item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combo box with 4 items. One of the items is "okay" which is a string. If this item is selected then I need to remove all other items in the combo box. How can I do this in XAML? Can I use control triggers?

Comment: Are you using mvvm pattern?

Comment: yes mvvm and the string "okay" is defined in the backend C# code. I am actually using control template trigger <Trigger Property = "ComboBox.SelectedItem" value="okay"><Setter Property="Visibility" value="collapsed"> but it's not working because SelectedItem refers to an object type?

Comment: can you post the portion of code both with xaml and c# viewmodel pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below.

In View:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLenses}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="230">
            </ComboBox>
```

In your ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> filteredLenses;
public ObservableCollection<string> FilteredLenses
{
    get
    {
        if (filteredLenses == null)
            filteredLenses = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        return filteredLenses;
    }
    set
    {
        filteredLenses = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FilteredLenses");
    }
}

public string selectedValue;
public string SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return selectedValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == "Okay")
        {
            // This logic can be done in many ways
            FilteredLenses.Clear();
            FilteredLenses.Add("Okay");

            OnPropertyChanged("FilteredLenses");
        }

        selectedValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
    }
}
```